# Mapping between Time and TimeSpan

Tags: linq-to-sql, mapping, sqldatatypes

in project I am mapping DbType Time to System.TimeSpan. It should by fine, but I am still getting error DBML1005. I have noticed that this is frequently asked topic on internet, but in all the other topics were about mapping custom datatypes.

> Error  1   DBML1005: Mapping between DbType 'Time NOT NULL' and Type 'System.TimeSpan' in Column 'RelayOnTime' of Type 'Terminal' is not supported.

```xml
<Column Name="RelayOnTime" Type="System.TimeSpan" DbType="Time NOT NULL"
        CanBeNull="false" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Visual Studio. I had Visual Studio 2008 RTM version, that still has some bugs. The solution is installing Service pack 1